# why cant i add php code inside a option tag?

Tags: php, html

I'm a newbie working on a project in php. I am trying to add a php code inside a html option tag. here is what I'm doing...

```
$companies = Company::find('all');
foreach ($companies as $c)
{
  echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ".if($c->id == $companyselected){'selected'}.">".$c->name."</option>" ;
}
```

`$companyselected` is the variable I pass from the controller which contains the id of the company that should be displayed at the top of the dropdown.
It outputs nothing. why cant i add like this.Is this correct to add like this.I'm stuck with this for long time. please help me out guys

Comment: $selected = ($c->id == $companyselected) ? 'selected' : '';
echo '<option .... '.$selected.'>'....:

Comment: it outputs all the company details....

Comment: You've tried to use an `if` statement in an `echo`.

Comment: Sorry friends Its working now... I too made a small mistake.. I mistyped my controller name... sorry if it troubled you... Thanks a lot guys..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ".(($c->id == $companyselected) ? 'selected=selected':'').">".$c->name."</option>" ;
```

**EDITED**

```
$str = "<option value='".$c->id."' ";
$str .= (($c->id == $companyselected) ? "selected='selected'":"");
$str .= ">".$c->name."</option>" ;
echo $str;
```

Comment: @PradeepG can you echo the both `$c->id` and `$companyselected` variables and let me know what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can't use if statement in echo.

```
$companies = Company::find('all');
foreach ($companies as $c)
{
    if($c->id == $companyselected) {
        echo "<option value='".$c->id."' selected='selected'>".$c->name."</option>" ;
    } else {
        echo "<option value='".$c->id."'>".$c->name."</option>" ;
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($companies as $c)
{
   $selected = ($c->id == $companyselected) ? 'selected' : '';
   echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ".$selected.">".$c->name."</option>" ;
}
```

Comment: first one works ... already i'm using that but... i had to make my code simpler with minimal typing and so i asked like that...

Comment: I think there is no more simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

Use [ternary operator](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/)

```
foreach ($companies as $c)
  {
   $selected = ($c->id == $companyselected) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
   echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ".$selected.">".$c->name."</option>" ;
  }
```

Comment: You sad it outputs nothing. Please put this `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in top of your file and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the write way to do this.

```
$companies = Company::find('all');
foreach ($companies as $c)
{
         echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ";
         if($c->id == $companyselected){
              echo 'selected';
         }
         echo ">".$c->name."</option>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$companies = Company::find('all');

$selected= '';

foreach ($companies as $c)
{
    if($c->id == $companyselected){
        $selected='selected';
    }
    echo "<option value='".$c->id."' ".$selected." >".$c->name."</option>" ;
}
```